# Using Application.Current.Properties to cache data is throwing error in Xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am developing a xamarin forms application. First of all, I am a newbie to xamarin and just started it today. But I am an experienced Android Developer. What I am trying to do now is I want to store local data of my application like SharedPreference in Android. So, the application will remember the data when the user reopens the app. I found those links that suggesting to use Application.Current.Properties - https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/106505/basic-local-storage-how-to and https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/application-class/. I tried it. But it is not working.

This is my testing code.

```
 public ItemDetailPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        setLabelValue();
        Application.Current.Properties["testing"] = "this is label restored from the local storage.";
        Application.Current.SavePropertiesAsync();
    }

    private void setLabelValue()
    {
        counter = 1;
        string testing = "this is default label";
        if(Application.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("testing"))
        {
            testing = Application.Current.Properties["testing"].ToString();
        }
        this.FindByName<Label>("labelTest").Text = testing;

    }
```

According to the code above, when I access that page for the first time it should set the label value as "this is default label". But for the consequent access, the label value should be "this is label restored form the local storage". When I access the page for the second time, it is giving me this error.
[image]

Comment: `SavePropertiesAsync` returns a `Task`, so you need to `await` it, i.e. `await Application.Current.SavePropertiesAsync();`

Comment: Actually it was throwing error. I just updated the question.

Comment: 1) Do not post images of errors/exceptions, they are not indexable, can not searched, hard to read on various devices, etc... 2) The error you are showing is concerning an `AudioRecord` object, not related to the app properties you are saving.

Comment: Now it is working guys. I dont know why. ZZZZZZ

Comment: Forget about Application.Current.Properties as its very slow, has problems with locks etc, use Xam.Plugins.Settings
 (https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/SettingsPlugin, docs: https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/SettingsPlugin/GettingStarted.html)

Comment: I agree with @ArtūrasPaleičikas, use Xam.Plugins.Settings. James Montemagno has a lot of good plugins that is worth trying out.

Comment: OK. I will try them out. Thank you all.